Как принять событие от иконки в области уведомлений для безоконной программы?
Я могу сделать кликабельную иконку для своего оконного приложения:
unit Unit1;

interface

 uses
  Windows,Messages,Forms,ShellApi,Dialogs;

 type
  TForm1=class(TForm)
   procedure IconMouse(var Msg:TMessage);message WM_USER+1;
   procedure FormCreate(Sender:TObject);
  end;

 var
  Form1:TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.IconMouse(var Msg:TMessage);
 begin
  case Msg.LParam of
   WM_LBUTTONUP:
    ShowMessage('Hi');
  end;
 end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender:TObject);
  var Nim:TNotifyIconData;
 begin
  with Nim do
   begin
    cbSize:=System.SizeOf(Nim);
    Wnd:=Form1.Handle;
    hicon:=Application.Icon.Handle;
    uID:=0;
    uFlags:=NIF_ICON or NIF_MESSAGE;
    uCallbackMessage:=WM_USER+1;
   end;
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD,@Nim);
 end;

end.

Но можно ли как-то сделать тоже самое, только для простой программы?
program Project1

begin
end.

Следуя аналогии, иконку создать получается, а вот как принять от неё сообщение -- не знаю.
program MyProgAaa1;

{$R *.res}

 uses
  Windows,Messages,ShellApi,Dialogs,
  Forms;

procedure IconMouse(var Msg:TMessage);
 begin
  case Msg.LParam of
   WM_LBUTTONUP:
    ShowMessage('Hi!');
  end;
 end;

var Nim:TNotifyIconData;

begin
 with Nim do
  begin
   cbSize:=System.SizeOf(Nim);
   Wnd:=Application.Handle;
   hicon:=Application.Icon.Handle;
   uID:=0;
   uFlags:=NIF_ICON or NIF_MESSAGE;
   uCallbackMessage:=WM_USER+1;
  end;
 Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD,@Nim);
 while True do
  //как сделать "PeekMessage" для IconMouse()?
end.


Никак, при добавлении новой иконки необходимо указывать дескриптор окна, которое будет получать от нее события. Другое дело, что окно не обязательно делать отображаемым на экране. Для таких случаев есть https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#message-only-windows

Использовать функцию AllocateHWnd, которая существует как раз для таких вещей. Передать ей на вход метод, который будет обрабатывать сообщения от иконки, а её результат присвоить полю Nim.Wnd. При завершении работы не забыть уничтожить созданное окно. А как реализовать цикл обработки сообщений можно посмотреть в исходниках Application.Run.

В Delphi сложно написать безоконное приложение, так как сам Application является главным окном. Видел что для подобных случаев пишут наследника от TApplication, который обрабатывает такие сообщения.


В Delphi сложно написать безоконное приложение

Нет, не сложно: File - New - Other - Delphi Projects - Console Application
Мало того - в примере этого вопроса оно как раз такое.

Варианты следующие:

Сделать невидимой главную (или любую) форму и в OnCreate также добавить   Application.ShowMainForm:=false;
Создать датамодуль и на него положить TTrayIcon.

